# Надо ли ставить запятую после "что" перед деепричастным оборотом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

*Олег знал, что(,) убежав с экзамена, он никогда не решит проблему.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

*Олег знал, что, **убежав с экзамена,** он никогда не решит проблему.*

> 2. Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения):
>    *Жизнь устроена так дьявольски, что, **не умея ненавидеть,** невозможно искренне любить* (Ж. Г.).

Источник: [**Деепричастные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113) (Розенталь).